# `Nodejs - Express` - getting error as `ReferenceError: bodyparser is not defined`

Tags: node.js, express

I am calling the `config` file from `server.js`. when i call the `config` file, I am getting the error as `ReferenceError: bodyparser is not defined`. I don't understand the wrong with my end.

any one help me to sort this?

here is my config file :

```
var 

path = require('path'),
routes = require('./routes'),
exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
errorHandler = require('errorhandler');


module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    app.use(bodyParser({
        uploadDir:path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')
    }));

    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
    routes(app);

    app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

    if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
        app.use(errorHandler());
    }

    return app;
};
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    config  = require('./server/configure'),
    app     = express();

app
    .set( "port", process.env.PORT || 3300 );

app
    .set( "views", __dirname + '/views');

app = config( app );

// app
//  .get('/', function( req, res ) {

//      res.send( 'Hello World' );

//  } );


app
    .listen( app.get('port'), function () {

        console.log('Server up: http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));

    })
```

**update**

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use(bodyParser({
        uploadDir:path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')
    }));

    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
    routes(app);

    app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

    if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
        app.use(errorHandler());
    }

    return app;
};
```

Comment: can you show you server.js file ?

Comment: server.js - added. see my question

Comment: Is it installed and included in `node_modules`?

Comment: yes. it is installed. that's what i am wondering here

Comment: It's weird that `bodyparser` in error is lowercase. At what line you get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following inside function in `config.js`

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyParser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

[Reference to bodyParser documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser)

Updated code:

In configure.js

```
var path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser({
        uploadDir:path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')
    }));
    return app;
};
```

In server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    config  = require('./configure'),
    app     = express();
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app = config( app );


app.post('/about', function( req, res ) {
            console.log(req.body.message);
            res.send( 'Hello World' );
    });
app.listen( 3000, function () {
            console.log('Server up: http://localhost:' + 3000);
        });
```

Comment: Still i am getting the same error. for the updated code see my update in quesiton

Comment: How are you sending the data in request ?

Comment: can you download from here and see : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ew7h43qvhhcy5r/NodeJs.7z?dl=0

Comment: The answer is updated for parsing other formats.  Does anyone those work? To check you can `console.log(req.body.username)` if username is the parameter send in body.

Comment: I updated yours and tried, while starting the node itself i am getting error

Comment: Okay, let me run it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107860/discussion-between-himani-agrawal-and-3gwebtrain).

Answer (score -1):

**TypeError:** Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
    at new module.exports (/home/dickens/Desktop/node-login/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:58:50)
    at Object. (/home/dickens/Desktop/node-login/app.js:56:14)

**change** directory of your **index.js** in the (/home/user/your-app/**node_modules**/connect-mongo/src/index.js:58:50)